# arrays must be of same length when creating a dataframe for boston housing prediction

Tags: dataframe

On writing this code, it generates error.  Why? 
`df=pd.DataFrame(boston)`.

The error it generates is `ValueError: arrays must all be same length` .

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the data of `boston` to get a confirmed answer.

It currently seems as if `boston` is an array of arrays. where the length of nested lists might not be the same. You may have to add padding to the lists.